# Objective-C setting the delegate for a collection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to set the delegate to be my UITextfield collection so that I can call `resignFirstResponder` on all of my textfields. What I've tried has not responded.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSMutableArray *textFields; 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_textFields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *textfield, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        textfield.delegate=self;
    }];
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textFields
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn Fired :)");
    [_textFields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *textfield, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        [textfield resignFirstResponder];
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The delegate method doesn't get called? Are there text fields in the collection?

Comment: What is not working? The textfields should resign regardless of their delegate. As Wain stated, make sure you actually have textfields in your collection.

Comment: You're sure these text fields exist? :)

Comment: I connected them in my XIB.

Comment: If you NSLog each textfield inside the enumeration blocks, what does that look like?

Comment: like this? - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textFields
{   [_textFields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *textfield, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        NSLog(@"_password"); NSLog(@"firstname");...                        or in the delegate one?

Comment: Make sure that you actually implement the expected delegate methods in your class.

Comment: Why are you making all of the textfields resign first responder? Surely just the one that the delegate method is being called for is enough?

Comment: How you are adding textfields in _textFields?

Comment: I've just connected them in the Xib. Should I add them programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `UITextFieldDelegate` in the .h?

```
@interface MyVC : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Also maybe try:

```
for (UITextField __strong *field in self.textFields)
   field.delegate = self;
```